# regular expression to print digits from specific location and prefix the digits with t

Tags: regex

I am very new to regular expression world and I have been trying to come up with a regular expression which will give me desired result. I have below pattern,

> :61:1503060306C1980,00F094033-86800**0000114**//1503060949876543

My main goal is to take 7 digits before `//` (Highlighted in bold). So the output of above string should come as `t0000114`. I tried creating `\d{7}\b//` but it gave me output as `0000114//` and I am not sure how can we get rid of `//` as well as prefix `t` to result set. I am using Expresso to test the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.*?(\d{7})\/\/.*$
```

Try this and replace by `t$1` or `t\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/20

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**capturing group**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) to retain the part you want matched/captured.

In the Design mode of Expresso, you would enter the following:

```
Regular Expression: (\d{7})//
Replacement String: t$1
```

One ran in Test Mode, the result would be:

```
:61:1503060306C1980,00F094033-86800t00001141503060949876543
                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I just need t0000114 from the complete pattern. Can we print only that part?

Answer (score 0):

This should capture a group for you

```
(\d{7}\b)
```

[This is how you can capture a group](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)